# Why is taking a slice of a list which is assigned to another list not changing the original?

Tags: python-3.x, list, slice, mutable

I have a class that is a representation of a mathematical tensor. The tensor in the class, is stored as a single list, not lists inside another list. That means `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]` would be stored as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.

I've made a `__setitem__()` function and a function to handle taking slices of this tensor while it's in single list format. For example `slice(1, None, None)` would become `slice(3, None, None)` for the list mentioned above. However when I assign this slice a new value, the original tensor isn't updated.

Here is what the simplified code looks like

```py
class Tensor:
    def __init__(self, tensor):
        self.tensor = tensor # Here I would flatten it, but for now imagine it's already flattened.

    def __setitem__(self, slices, value):
        slices = [slices] 
        temp_tensor = self.tensor # any changes to temp_tensor should also change self.tensor.

        for s in slices: # Here I would call self.slices_to_index(), but this is to keep the code simple.
            temp_tensor = temp_tensor[slice]

        temp_tensor = value # In my mind, this should have also changed self.tensor, but it hasn't.
```

Maybe i'm just being stupid and can't see why this isn't working. Maybe my actual questions isn't just ' why doesn't this work?' but also 'is there a better way to do this?'. Thanks for any help you can give me.

NOTES:

Each 'dimension' of the list must have the same shape, so `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]` isn't allowed.

This code is massively simplified as there are many other helper functions and stuff like that.

in `__init__()` I would flatten the list but as I just said to keep things simple I left that out, along with `self.slice_to_index()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not think of python variables as in `c++` or `java`. Think of them as labels you place on values. Check this example:

```
>>> l = []
>>> l.append
<built-in method append of list object at 0x7fbb0d40cf88>
>>> l.append(10)
>>> l
[10]
>>> ll = l
>>> ll.append(10)
>>> l
[10, 10]
>>> ll
[10, 10]
>>> ll = ["foo"]
>>> l
[10, 10]
```

As you can see, `ll` variable first points to the same `l` list but later we just make it point to another list. Modifying the later `ll` won't modify the original list pointed by `l`.

So, in your case if you want `self.tensor` to point to a new value, just do it:

```
class Tensor:
    def __init__(self, tensor):
        self.tensor = tensor # Here I would flatten it, but for now imagine it's already flattened.

    def __setitem__(self, slices, value):
        slices = [slices] 
        temp_tensor = self.tensor # any changes to the list pointed by temp_tensor will be reflected in self.tensor since it is the same list

        for s in slices: 
            temp_tensor = temp_tensor[slice]

        self.tensor = value
```

Comment: That makes sense, so I can now see why my original function wasn't working. I'll try your approach to it.